# Problems using a sentinel value and with outputs/inputs delaying/duplicating

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int userInput(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel);
int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel);

int main(void)
{
   int Length;      // The length of the story.
   int counter = 0;
   int numA = 0;
   int numB = 0;
   int numC = 0;
   char AuthorLevel;    // The level of the author.
   float PayOut;        // The final payout.
   float averagePayout = 0.0;
   float highestPayout = 0.0;

   userInput(Length, AuthorLevel);
   computePay(Length, AuthorLevel);

   system( "pause" );
   return 0;
} //end main()
//==================================================================

int userInput(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel )
{
   cout << "Please enter the word count of the story (-1 to stop): ";
   cin >> Length;
   if( Length != -1)
   {
      cout << "Now enter the author's level (A, B, or C): ";
      cout << "Level: ";
      cin >> AuthorLevel;
      cout << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      system( "pause" );
      return 0;
   }
}

//==================================================================
int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel)
{
   float PayOut;        // The final payout.
   int numA = 0; // Number of A's that have been printed.
   int numB = 0; // Total number of B's.
   int numC = 0; // Number of C's.
   float averagePayout = 0.0;
   float highestPayout = 0.0;
   int counter = 0; // The number of times the program has ran.

   while( Length != -1)
   {
      if(Length < 7500 || Length != -1)
      {
         PayOut = 0.08 * Length;
      }
      else if(Length < 8000)
      {
         PayOut = 600;
      }
      else if(Length < 17500)
      {
         PayOut = 0.075 * Length;
      }
      else if(Length < 19000)
      {
         PayOut = 1313;
      }
      else if(Length >= 19000)
      {
         PayOut = 0.07 * Length;
      };

      if (AuthorLevel == 'A' || AuthorLevel == 'a')
      {
         numA++;
         PayOut = 1.75 * PayOut;
      }
      else if(AuthorLevel == 'B' || AuthorLevel == 'b')
      {
         numB++;
         PayOut = 1.25 * PayOut;
      }
      else if (AuthorLevel == 'C' || AuthorLevel == 'c')
      {
         numC++;
         PayOut = 1.00 * PayOut;
      }
      else
      {
         cout << "That was not a valid input. Please try again." << endl;
      };

      userInput(Length, AuthorLevel);
      counter++;
      cout << "The amount the author will make from the story will be: $" << PayOut;
      cout << endl << endl;
      cout << "The number of payments calculated is: " << counter << endl;
      cout << "The number of A's inputted: " << numA << endl;
      cout << "The number of B's inputted: " << numB << endl;
      cout << "The number of C's inputted: " << numC << endl;
      averagePayout = (averagePayout += PayOut) / counter;
      if(highestPayout < PayOut)
      {
         highestPayout = PayOut;
      }
      else if(highestPayout > PayOut)
      {
         highestPayout = highestPayout;
      }
      cout << "The highest payout so far has been: $" << highestPayout << endl;
      cout << "The average payout is: $" << averagePayout << endl << endl;
   }
}
//===================================================
```

This program keeps outputting the first function multiple times before working, and the first output first the second function keeps outputting the inputs for the first input, and -1 isn't stopping the entire program like it should. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

> This program keeps outputting the first function multiple times before working and the first output first the second function keeps outputting the inputs for the first input

You have a call to `userInput` from `computePay`. That explains the above behavior.

> and -1 isn't stopping the entire program like it should. Could anyone help?

After the call to `userInput` from `computePay`, you don't have any code to break out of the loop if `Length == -1`. Hence, you get more output from the following `printf` calls.

My suggestions:

1. Change `main` slightly so that the flow of control is simpler. Replace the lines:

   ```
   userInput(Length, AuthorLevel);
   computePay(Length, AuthorLevel);
   ```

   by

   ```
   while (1)
   {
      userInput(Length, AuthorLevel);
      if ( Length == -1 )
      {
         break;
      }
      computePay(Length, AuthorLevel);
   }
   ```
2. Remove the call to `userInput` from `computePay`.
3. Remove the `while` loop from `computePay`.
4. The logic behind the following line is not clear to me:

   ```
   averagePayout = (averagePayout += PayOut) / counter;
   ```

   You should simplify it. I get a compiler warning from that line that  says:

```
    socc.cc: In function ‘int computePay(int&, char&)’:
    socc.cc:108:58: warning: operation on ‘averagePayout’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
           averagePayout = (averagePayout += PayOut) / counter;
```

Here's an updated version of your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int userInput(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel);
int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel);

int main(void)
{
   int Length;      // The length of the story.
   int counter = 0;
   int numA = 0;
   int numB = 0;
   int numC = 0;
   char AuthorLevel;    // The level of the author.
   float PayOut;        // The final payout.
   float averagePayout = 0.0;
   float highestPayout = 0.0;

   while (1)
   {
      userInput(Length, AuthorLevel);
      if ( Length == -1 )
      {
         break;
      }
      computePay(Length, AuthorLevel);
   }

   return 0;
} //end main()
//==================================================================

int userInput(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel )
{
   cout << "Please enter the word count of the story (-1 to stop): ";
   cin >> Length;
   if( Length != -1)
   {
      cout << "Now enter the author's level (A, B, or C): ";
      cout << "Level: ";
      cin >> AuthorLevel;
      cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}

//==================================================================
int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel)
{
   float PayOut;        // The final payout.
   int numA = 0; // Number of A's that have been printed.
   int numB = 0; // Total number of B's.
   int numC = 0; // Number of C's.
   float averagePayout = 0.0;
   float highestPayout = 0.0;
   int counter = 0; // The number of times the program has ran.

   if(Length < 7500 || Length != -1)
   {
      PayOut = 0.08 * Length;
   }
   else if(Length < 8000)
   {
      PayOut = 600;
   }
   else if(Length < 17500)
   {
      PayOut = 0.075 * Length;
   }
   else if(Length < 19000)
   {
      PayOut = 1313;
   }
   else if(Length >= 19000)
   {
      PayOut = 0.07 * Length;
   };

   if (AuthorLevel == 'A' || AuthorLevel == 'a')
   {
      numA++;
      PayOut = 1.75 * PayOut;
   }
   else if(AuthorLevel == 'B' || AuthorLevel == 'b')
   {
      numB++;
      PayOut = 1.25 * PayOut;
   }
   else if (AuthorLevel == 'C' || AuthorLevel == 'c')
   {
      numC++;
      PayOut = 1.00 * PayOut;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "That was not a valid input. Please try again." << endl;
   };

   counter++;
   cout << "The amount the author will make from the story will be: $" << PayOut;
   cout << endl << endl;
   cout << "The number of payments calculated is: " << counter << endl;
   cout << "The number of A's inputted: " << numA << endl;
   cout << "The number of B's inputted: " << numB << endl;
   cout << "The number of C's inputted: " << numC << endl;

   // FIXME
   averagePayout = (averagePayout += PayOut) / counter;
   // FIXME

   if(highestPayout < PayOut)
   {
      highestPayout = PayOut;
   }
   else if(highestPayout > PayOut)
   {
      highestPayout = highestPayout;
   }
   cout << "The highest payout so far has been: $" << highestPayout << endl;
   cout << "The average payout is: $" << averagePayout << endl << endl;

   return 0;
}
//===================================================
```

Comment: Thank you! For averagePayout = (averagePayout += PayOut) / counter; I'm trying to calculate an average of all the payouts that have been printed, sorry if it wasn't clear. With the numA, numB, and numC, variables, I'm trying to get a total of how many A's, B's, and C's have been entered.